# How to place the iterated string variable in another string

Tags: python, selenium

Quick overview: I am writing a a very simple script using Python and Selenium to view Facebook Metrics for multiple Facebook pages.

I am trying to find a clean way to loop through the pages and output their results (it's only one number that I am collecting).

Here is what I have right now but it is not working.

```
# Navigate to metrics page

pages = ["page_example_1", "page_example_2", "page_example_3"]

for link in pages:
    browser.get(('https://www.facebook.com/{link}/insights/?section=navVideos'))
```

Comment: Try `browser.get(('https://www.facebook.com/{}/insights/?section=navVideos'.format(link)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Navigate to metrics page

pages = ["page_example_1", "page_example_2", "page_example_3"]

for link in pages:
    browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/'+ link + '/insights/?section=navVideos')
```

its just string concatenation
or if you are so much inclined to use that syntax, have a look at the comment by [@heather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412998/using-variables-to-view-multipe-pages#comment89797646_51412998)

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for you, because you aimed to use Python 3.6's f-strings, but forgot to prepend your string with the `f` char - crucial for this syntax. E.g. your code should be (only the relevant part):

```
browser.get(f'https://www.facebook.com/{link}/insights/?sights/?section=navVideos')
```

Alternatively you could use string formatting (e.g. the established approach before 3.6):

```
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/{}/insights/?sights/?section=navVideos'.format(link))
```

In general, string concatenation - `'string1' + variable + 'string2'` - is discouraged in python for performance and readability reasons.

---

BTW, in your sample code you had brackets around the `get()`'s argument - it is `browser.get((arg))`, which essentially turned it to a tuple, and might've caused error in the call. Not sure was it a typo or on purpose, as you can see I and the other responders have removed it.